# fread doesn't change the pointer value in a function ( Cause infinite Loop with a feof ) - C

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks, infinite-loop, fread

```
int ricerca_copia(int x,int xf)
{

FILE *xp;
int conf;
int f;
int xeof;

f=0;
// file was already written and closed before this function
xp=fopen("prenotazioni_copy.dat","rb");
if(xp)
{
  xeof=0;

  while(xeof==0)
  {
    //Never changes xp value
    fread(&appoggio,sizeof(appoggio),1,xp);
    if(feof(xp))
    {
     //never enters here

        xeof=1;
    }
    else
    {
            //other stuff
    }
    fclose(xp);

  }
}
printf("\nValore %d",f);
return f;
}
```

fread doesn't change pointer (xp) value,so the xeof value remains 0 and the loop restarts

I have tested already to use this part of code externally of this function and it works,so the problem is this.

I don't really know how to solve,so there are any solution?

Comment: Try and have complete examples. Here `appoggio` is never defined, so it's of unknown type. You'll also want to check for errors on each operation, not just some of them.

Comment: `fread` has a return value that you **must** check. If it is not equal to what you pass as the `nmemb`, *then* you **must** check `errno` or `ferror` to find out if an error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you call `fclose(xp)` in your loop.

Do first iteration works okay, but next `fread` call fails (you should check what `fread` returns BTW, it's supposed to return the number of elements read, so if it doesn't and returns 0 or -1 there's a problem), and so does `feof` on that handle (well, actually it's undefined behaviour as stated here: [What is the return value of feof() on a closed file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179543/what-is-the-return-value-of-feof-on-a-closed-file))

You mean to call `fclose(xp)` *outside* the loop or you get an infinite loop (unless the file is smaller that the size of the struct, which is another functional error)

Aside: `xp` is a pointer on `FILE` opaque structure. It doesn't change even with multiple `fread`. Which changes is some hidden `offset` value. But you cannot get that information unless you call `ftell` on the handle.